# Automated Malware Analysis Tools as a standalone

Tags: malware, tools, automated-testing

I am in search of automated malware analysis tools in order to list and evaluate/benchmark, but I can't find solutions that work as a standalone. Most of what I found is online or requires buying a corporate license, something that I can not do as the research is intended for acedemic purposes. Mainly my search results have been proposals of solutions in scientific publications that cannot be tested. I would be grateful if someone could suggest solutions such as Cuckoo Sandbox or sources that list such software.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/rshipp/awesome-malware-analysis#online-scanners-and-sandboxes

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try Limon sandbox. (for Linux malware)
https://github.com/monnappa22/Limon